# Accelerating of Geopandas for selecting the points inside a polygon

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have one dataset with about 10 million points(lat e long). I would like to select the points that fall within a map. I have this map as a Shaply object (shp). To do this, I transformed the localization of each point into a Point object using `points_from_xy`. So I transformed my DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame. 
My map is in the form of a Multipolygon object. So I used `geometry.unary_union` to convert it into a unified polygon (I'm not sure if it is correct). Then I used the `within` method in Geopandas to select the Points inside the map.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import geopandas as gpd
    from tqdm import tqdm

    map = gpd.read_file('foo.shp')
    df = pd.read_csv('foo1.csv')
    points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude))
    map = map.geometry.unary_union
    within_points = [points.geometry[i].within(map) for i in tqdm(range(points.geometry.count()))]
    within_points = points[within_points]
```

My problem is that this process takes TOO long (about 5 days on my core i5 laptop). I would like to know if there is any way to accelerate it.

Comment: You will need to use spatial index - https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/spatial_index.html

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346550/accelerating-geopandas-for-selecting-points-inside-polygon/346710#346710